# Flask: how to set up object position (tables, charts) inside a report

Tags: python, charts, flask, report, reportlab

I understand that to some this might look vague but: what part of documentation should i look at when trying to do the following:

I have:

a) a table: a dataframe created using pandas to be precise

b) a chart coming from any number of chart-producing-libraries (plotlib / seaborn / etc)

and i want to simply want to prep them in a (less advanced) fashion such as the one displayed here (http://www.reportlab.com/media/imadj/data/RLIMG_41e9a00cdb0698a0dca740ed26ffa4dc.PDF)

I am not looking for an exact solution but it would be nice to be pointed in the right direction in terms of documentation.

Comment: pandas has a .to_html() method; see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html). Flask will gladly serve that. Best (to get the ball rolling with little formatting) is is to pass the generated html table to a template (as a parameter in render_template). As for the plotting, you'll have to research it yourself (search for 'flask plots', or any similar terms). There are too many ways to do this to provide a simple answer. Post a specific question when you run into trouble.

Comment: thank you! that was what I was looking for